# Displaying default image when there is no image

Tags: php, html, arrays

I want to display a default image when no image is uploaded in the CMS.

So far I got this code:

```
<li><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="
                        <? if($artikel[0]['images'] == ''){ ?>
                                images/defaultimg.jpg
                        <? }else{ ?>
                        cms/images/<?

                                $plaatje = $artikel[0]['images'];
                                $plaatje = explode('\/', $plaatje);
                                $plaatje = $plaatje[1];
                                $plaatje = explode('"', $plaatje);
                                $plaatje = $plaatje[0];
                                echo $plaatje;

                        }
                        ?>"></li>
```

But this does not display the image. I know the image is there, so I think something is wrong with the outputted html code.

Anyone see it?

Thanks

Output code as requested:

```
<img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="
                                                                cms/images/">
```

I got the correct code:

```
                <?php
                  $image = "images/defaultimg.jpg";

                  $pl = $artikel[0]['images'];
                  $pl = explode('\/', $pl);
                  $pl = $pl[1];
                  $pl = explode('"', $pl);
                  $pl = $pl[0];
                  $pl = explode('.', $pl);
                  $pl = $pl[1];

                  echo $pl;

                  if($pl == 'jpg'){ //Check if string is empty
                      $plaatje = $artikel[0]['images'];
                      $plaatje = explode('\/', $plaatje);
                      $plaatje = $plaatje[1];
                      $plaatje = explode('"', $plaatje);
                      $plaatje = $plaatje[0];
                      // If the string supplied in the if condition isn't empty i assume that there's an image
                      // so i prepend the imagefolder as source
                      $image = 'cms/images/'.$plaatje;
                  }

                  $html = '<li><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="'.$image.'"></li>';

                  echo $html

                ?>
```

Comment: What's the output code ?

Comment: Try to echo you default image address: echo 'images/defaultimg.jpg'; May be problem becouse of \n characters in url

Comment: @okio, i added it.

Aleksandr, that didn't do it unfortunately.

Comment: you're not closing the `src="` property

Comment: Dear questioner, you should add an example of what you initally have in $artikel[0]['images'];
@Azrael he is closing it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just separate the if else logic from your markup instead of cluttering it up on that source attribute. Example:

```
<?php

$image = '';
if($artikel[0]['images'] == '') {
    $image = 'images/defaultimg.jpg'; // wrap it with quotes
} else {
    $plaatje = $artikel[0]['images'];
    $plaatje = explode('\/', $plaatje);
    $plaatje = $plaatje[1];
    $plaatje = explode('"', $plaatje);
    $image = 'cms/images/' . $plaatje[0]; // append the filename with that particular path
}

?>

<li><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></li>
```

Comment: what does `$artikel[0]['images']` contain anyways? do you have a sample string for this?

Comment: It's for an article, since it's non joomla site added to a joomla cms.

The code always outputs: <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="cms/images/">

I wonder why? There is no image, so why is it looking in the cms directory

Comment: @user50248 so `$artikel[0]['images']` is actually an empty string? are you sure? `var_dump($artikel[0]['images'])`

Comment: It's not apparently, 

string(173) "{"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_a

Comment: so `$artikel[0]['images']` contains that string? oh my. looks like a json string. looks like you need to `json_decode($artikel[0]['images'])` first

Comment: I got some help, had to search for '.jpg' in the string, if it's not there then the code displays the default image.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<li><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="
                        <?php if(empty($artikel[0]['images'])){ 
                                echo "images/defaultimg.jpg";
                         }else{ 


                                $plaatje = $artikel[0]['images'];
                                $plaatje = explode('\/', $plaatje);
                                $plaatje = $plaatje[1];
                                $plaatje = explode('"', $plaatje);
                                $plaatje = $plaatje[0];
                                echo "cms/images/".$plaatje;

                        }
                        ?>"></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

AS @Ghost says, separe the logic from view, another solution more clean:

```
<?php

    if (empty($artikel[0]['images']){
        $artikel[0]['images'] = 'images/defaultimg.jpg';
    }else{
        $artikel[0]['images'] = 'cms/images/' . basename($artikel[0]['images']);
    }

?>

<li><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $artikel[0]['images']; ?>"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to be in the layout of your code, as you cleary see in your output you got linebreaks and probably more unknown unknowns.

Better refactor it so something like this.

```
<?php
  $image = "images/defaultimg.jpg";
  if($artikel[0]['images'] != ''){ //Check if string is empty
      $plaatje = $artikel[0]['images']; //Do your magic here
      $plaatje = explode('\/', $plaatje);
      $plaatje = $plaatje[1];
      $plaatje = explode('"', $plaatje);
      $plaatje = $plaatje[0];
      // If the string supplied in the if condition isn't empty i assume that there's an image
      // so i prepend the imagefolder as source
      $image = 'cms/images/'.$plaatje;
  }

  $html = '<li><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="$image"></li>';

  echo $html

?>
```

First of all this will raise the readability of your code, and second of all you can see without a headache what you're trying to do there.

This way you don't have to care about 2 cases, you got one case to take care of, the rest is handled by the default variable.

But pay attention there, in your $artikel[0]['images'] there could also be some errors, so in the end you would add an errorstring to your imagesource, which you don't wan't.

Whenever you're showing something to your user you should check if that file exists. There once again you got your unknown unknowns sitting in that variable.

The assignment of your Variable would then look like this

```
if(file_exists('cms/images/'.$plaatje)){
   $image = 'cms/images/'.$plaatje;
}
```

This will prevent the above issues, and since you got a single point of exit, the person working on that code after you will be grateful.

Comment: Thanks for answering, when I use your code it uses cms/images as the source. Which is not what I want when an image is not found.

Comment: @user50248 See my comments in the edited answer, if your string isn't empty i assume theres a picture. If it is empty the condition isn't true and for that it won't run through that statements, that's why i initialize the variable at the top, so you only have to care about cases you expect to happen

Answer (score 0):

I got the correct code.

```
                        <?php
                          $image = "images/defaultimg.jpg";

                          $pl = $artikel[0]['images'];
                          $pl = explode('\/', $pl);
                          $pl = $pl[1];
                          $pl = explode('"', $pl);
                          $pl = $pl[0];
                          $pl = explode('.', $pl);
                          $pl = $pl[1];

                          echo $pl;

                          if($pl == 'jpg'){ //Check if string is empty
                              $plaatje = $artikel[0]['images'];
                              $plaatje = explode('\/', $plaatje);
                              $plaatje = $plaatje[1];
                              $plaatje = explode('"', $plaatje);
                              $plaatje = $plaatje[0];
                              // If the string supplied in the if condition isn't empty i assume that there's an image
                              // so i prepend the imagefolder as source
                              $image = 'cms/images/'.$plaatje;
                          }

                          $html = '<li><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="'.$image.'"></li>';

                          echo $html

                        ?>
```

Comment: well, whatever works for you, anyway this should have been an edit on the question, and another sidenote: i think you're trying to get the file_name on that json_string which is not good, i can see now why you're trying to explode that string `\/`. most likely from that escape backslashes from that url path. i suggest parse them with `json_decode()` instead. but anyway. if it works, it works